# how to display the parent and child alternatively using with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have list with parent and children.

```
Title1
 child1
 child2
 child3
Title2
 child1
 child2
 child3
```

i want to print the parent and children as like this

```
title1_child1
title1_child2
title1_child3
title2_child1
title2_child2
title3_child2
```

thanks in advance

Comment: so what distinguishes parent from children in your list?

Comment: @Petar the indentation I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the below layout you can try this

```
<ul>
  <li><span>Title1</span>
     <ul>
        <li>Child1</li>
        <li>Child2</li>
        <li>Child3</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Title1</span>
     <ul>
        <li>Child1</li>
        <li>Child2</li>
        <li>Child3</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="output"></div>

$(function(){
  var parent, str = "", $this;
  $("ul:first li").each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    parent = $this.find("span").text();
    str = "";
    $this.find("li").each(function(){
      str = str + parent + "_" + $(this).text() + "<br />";
    });
    $(".output").html(str);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var string="";
$(".title childTag").each(function(){
  string += $(this).closest(".title").html() + "_" + $(this).html();
})
```

Something like that